# Determine the degree of the field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> Determine the degree of the field extension
> ($1$st task) $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\sqrt[4]{6},\sqrt[5]{7})/\mathbb{Q}$,
> ($2$nd task) $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt[10]{75})/\mathbb{Q}$,
> ($3$rd task) $N/\mathbb{Q}$, where $N$ is the splitting field  of the polynomial $X^5-3\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Studying for my upcoming algebra exam, I found this exercise from an old algebra exam.

So far I have:

- The first task

For the $\sqrt[3]{5}$ we have
$\alpha = \sqrt[3]{5} \rightarrow \alpha^3-5=0$ is the minimal polynomial, so we have $f(t)=t^3-5$. The Eisenstein criteria is fulfilled with $p=5$, so the degree is $\deg(f(t))=3$.

So for $\sqrt[4]{6}$ the degree should be $4$ and for $\sqrt[5]{7}$ the degree should be $5$. But I am not sure how to proceed from here, because normally you should factorize the given numbers which is not possible here.

- The second task

$\sqrt[2]{3}$ so the minimal polynomial should be $\alpha^2-3=0$ and the degree is $2$. The term $\sqrt[5]{75}$ can be factorized into $\sqrt[5]{75}=\sqrt[5]{25} \cdot \sqrt[5]{3}=\sqrt[5]{5} \cdot \sqrt[5]{5} \cdot \sqrt[5]{3}$, but I am unsure how to proceed to determine degree from here.

- The third task

For the third task I unfortunately have no idea how to start solving it. Maybe someone could give me hint?

**Edit** Thanks for the quick answer. For the third task the splitting field is $\mathbb Q(\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]3)$. So I think the degree of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[5]{3}]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is 5 because the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$. And the solutions for the polynomial are $\alpha=\sqrt[5]{3}$ times the $5$th roots of unity $\zeta_5=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$, that is $\alpha, \alpha \zeta_5, \alpha \zeta_5^2, \alpha \zeta_5^3$ and $\alpha \zeta_5^4$. Then the degree of $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_5]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is 4. So the degree of the splitting field should be $[\mathbb{Q}[\alpha, \zeta_5]:\mathbb{Q}]=20$, because $4$ and $5$ have no common divisor.

Is this right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the third task, the splitting field is $\mathbb Q(\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]3)$, where $\zeta_5$ is a primitive fifth root of unity.

Comment: Your proof in the edit is fine (assuming it is known that $\Bbb Q(\zeta_5)$ has degree $4$ over $\Bbb Q$). Note that you can argue in the same way using that the degrees are coprime in the first task and also similarly in the second.

Comment: @leoli1 Sorry that I'm asking, but would you mind elobariting on the first and second task? Showing me the path towards the solution would be very helpful ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first task: You already noted that \begin{align*}
[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5}):\Bbb Q]&=3\\
[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{6}):\Bbb Q]&=4\\
[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]{7}):\Bbb Q]&=5
\end{align*}
Since these degrees are pairwise coprime the corresponding field extensions are pairwise linearly disjoint and we get as you did in task three:
\begin{align*}
[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5},\sqrt[4]{6},\sqrt[5]{7}):\Bbb Q]&=[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5}):\Bbb Q][\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{6}):\Bbb Q][\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]{7}):\Bbb Q]=3\cdot 4\cdot 5 = 60
\end{align*}

For the second task: We can do this actually a bit quicker than the way I hinted in the comment. Note that $$(\sqrt[10]{75})^5=5\cdot\sqrt{3}$$
Hence $$\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt[10]{75})=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[10]{75})$$
And $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[10]{75})$ has degree $10$ over $\Bbb Q$ since $t^{10}-75$ is irreducible.